# Filter a Table with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just got into AngularJS and I'm trying to filter a table. So far I create my table dynamically, which works fine.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="tableApp" ng-controller="tableAppController">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchKey" placeholder="search..."/>

                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-striped" id="trackingTable">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.r.</th>
                                        <th>a</th>
                                        <th>b</th>
                                        <th>c</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="x in deviceData">
                                        <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                                        <td>{{x.a}}</td>
                                        <td>{{x.b}}</td>
                                        <td>{{x.c}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script src="scripts/AngularJS/tableAppController.js"></script>
```

tableAppController.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tableApp', []);
app.controller('tableAppController', function ($scope) {
$scope.deviceData = [{a: "123", b: "123", c: "01.01.2001"}, {a: "dummyDeviceID2", b: "dummyCarID98", c: "01.01.2001"}];
});
```

I'm now trying to implement an filter, which filters data from the table based on an user input from a textfield. But only when a user types something inside the textbox ofcourse. I started to change the line `<tr ng-repeat="x in deviceData">` in the html file to `<tr ng-repeat="x in deviceData | filter:{'a':searchKey}">` Why is this approach not working and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use keys on your search object to do this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchKey.a" placeholder="search..."/>

<tr ng-repeat="x in deviceData | filter:searchKey">
```

See line 36 in the official example for more context: http://plnkr.co/edit/YUfG7yzxBQ0gT9bsnTN2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}

<tr ng-repeat="x in deviceData | filter : searchKey">
```

**AngularJS Official Documentation :** [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

**Plnkr :** http://plnkr.co/edit/r6cchqzftaRiH543L1NE?p=preview

Comment: This will not filter only on the `a` property, as OP requested

Comment: @tyler, i checked and its working file. I updated the plnkr..please check.

Comment: Perfect -- type 98 into your plunkr's search box and you will see that it's not filtering on the `a` property only.  However if you change line 10 to read `ng-model="searchKey.a"` (as suggested in my answer), it will filter on the `a` property only